# Have scroll be on child element instead on resizable parent

Tags: html, css

I have this large table that sits in a floating resizable div between two sticky divs (header and footer).

But, when this table overflows, the scrolling then sits on the parent floating div, instead of the div itself, which messes up the sticky divs when I scroll horizontally.

Example :

[image]

Of course this would work by setting the table with a fixed width/height but I need it to be automatic since it sits in a resizable div.

How can I make this work? Basically I want the table div to be having the scroll, instead of its parent, like this great paint edit:

[image]

While maintaining auto sizing of course.

The header/footer should not scroll horizontally.

Here's the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/nhy02w3v/18/

Html :

```
<div class="floating-middle">
  <div class="sticky sticky-top">
    I'm a sticky header
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
      <th>Column5</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     ...
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="sticky sticky-bottom">
    I'm a sticky footer
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  display: flex;
  width : 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.floating-middle{
  align-self : center;
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sticky-top{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.sticky-bottom{
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.sticky{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll
}`

https://jsfiddle.net/fpqamh45/

Maybe this is what you want?

Comment: Not quite, the horizontal scroll should be fixed and not hidden at the bottom

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/we6p917r/ I edited a little, to fixed scrollbar at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `overflow:auto` to `table-wrapper` class, so that table's scroll is bounded only to the `table-wrapper` div.

You can check in the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sivadass/f47vmhwp/)

Comment: Nope, that's not it, the horizontal scroll should be fixed and always showing